# Pine Script - bgcolor() one day into the future

Tags: pine-script

I want to color the background of certain timeframes (pre-trading, pre-market, after-hours) during the day. The code below works, except I also want the background to be colored *one day into the future*, so I can visually grasp in advance when the price graph is approaching the end of the trading session and the beginning of after-hours.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Trading Hours", overlay=true)

bgcolor(timeframe.isintraday and time("", "0200-0800", "GMT+2") ? color.new(color.orange , 92) : na)
bgcolor(timeframe.isintraday and time("", "0800-0900", "GMT+2") ? color.new(color.blue, 95) : na)
bgcolor(timeframe.isintraday and time("", "1730-2200", "GMT+2") ? color.new(color.blue, 95) : na)
```

New to Pine Script, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to color future bars. You can however use the `offset` parameter, but you'll have to calculate the equivalent of 24 hours for each timeframe and manually input it in the parameter since it only accepts constant values.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Trading Hours", overlay=true)

bgcolor(timeframe.isintraday and time("", "0200-0800", "GMT+2") ? color.new(color.orange , 92) : na, offset=48)
bgcolor(timeframe.isintraday and time("", "0800-0900", "GMT+2") ? color.new(color.blue, 95) : na, offset=48)
bgcolor(timeframe.isintraday and time("", "1730-2200", "GMT+2") ? color.new(color.blue, 95) : na, offset=48)
```

The script uses 48 as the `offset`, it adjusts colors by 48 hours into the future since I'm currently on the 1 hour chart. If you're on the 5 min chart, offsetting it by 48 will adjust the colors by 240 mins since 48*5mins = 240 mins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `offset` is indeed the solution. Thank you very much! I was able to dynamically calculate the needed `offset` depending on the displayed resolution by `offset = 1170 / timeframe.multiplier`. The 1170 are the number of minutes in my securities (extended) trading session (starts at 2:30, ends at 22:00). The 1170 offset doesn't work on securities that are traded 24 hours though... Any idea on how to also dynamically calculate the number of minutes in a trading session of the currently viewed security?